# Find the PDF of $X$

Tags: probability

> Suppose that a narrow beam flashlight is spun around its center as in the figure below when the flashlight has stopped spinning, consider the point $X$ at which the beam intersects the $x$-axis. Note that the point $X$ can be determined from the angle $\theta$ between the flashlight and the $y$-axis.
>
> It is further assumed that $\theta\sim \text{Unif}\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Find the PDF of $X$.

[image]

---

I have set $\tan(\Theta)=X$ with $P(X\le x)=P(\tan\Theta \le x)$.

$$P(\Theta \ge \tan^{-1}x)=1-F_{\Theta}(\tan^{-1}x)=1-\frac{\tan^{-1}x+\pi/2}{\pi/2+\pi/2},\\
P(X\le x)=1-\frac{\tan^{-1}x+\pi/2}{\pi/2+\pi/2}$$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0$ otherwise.

I am wondering if my solution is plausible. Any hint at any error will be more than welcome.

Comment: In the given range, $\tan \Theta $ is monotone increasing. So why did you flip the inequality ? Also you've not enclosed the figure.

Comment: flipped it because of $R_{\theta}$ which is not entirely positive

Comment: I think you're right since it's increasing on $R_{\theta}$ I shouldn't flip it thank you for the remark.

Comment: $P(\Theta \le tan^{-1}(x))=F_{\Theta}(tan^{-1}x)$=$\frac{tan^{-1}x+\pi/2}{\pi/2+\pi/2}$

$$P(X\le x)=\frac{tan^{-1}x+\pi/2}{\pi/2+\pi/2}$$ with x$\in \Re$ and 0 otherwise

Comment: Yes, $X$ has the well known standard Cauchy distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you did is correct. You have one mistake, which is the final result. All you need to do is say: 
$$P(X\leq x) = F_{\Theta}(\tan^{-1}x)=\frac{\tan^{-1}x+\pi/2}{\pi/2+\pi/2}$$ and that's it. Why did you go around saying $P(\Theta \ge \tan^{-1}x)$ ? You write $$P(X\le x)=P(\tan\Theta \le x)$$
which means that 
$$P(X\leq x) = F_{\Theta}(\tan^{-1} x)$$
because $\tan$ is increasing in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.